# Notepad++ : Do batch text replace

Tags: batch, notepad++, find-and-replace

I'm trying to create a dictionary file from several webpages I found online. The dictionary indexes headwords so that they can be easily found in search mode. The information in the webpage is divided into sections each with a unique ID. For example:
`<div id="word-2857">Andronicus, Titus  . . .`

The problem is there are reference links in other text to other words written as: `<a href="#word-2857"><i>see Titus Andronicus</i></a>`

So when creating a dictionary file (for Goldendict) references to other words must written as: `<a href="entry://headword">text to display</a>`

Since making headwords word-2857 instead of Andronicus, Titus is pretty useless what I want to do (finally) is to do batch replacement of links for all words (there are about 10,000 of them). I mean I want to replace all ID links to their corresponding headword. `<a href="#word-2857"><i>see Titus Andronicus</i></a>` should become `<a href="entry://Andronicus, Titus">see Titus Andronicus</a>`

I already have a list of all the words I want to replace with what I want to replace them. The problem is that using Notepad++ I can only do one unique replacement at a time. There are more than 10,000 words and this will take too long. Please help in explaining how this can be done easily.

**Thanks**

Comment: Do the reference links always have the same structure? (what you want is always "LastWord, FirstWord", and what is there is always "see FirstWord LastWord". If there's a certain structure to it, it could be done with Regex. We need to know the structure, or if there are 2 or 3 different structures, all of the possible structures.

Comment: Or if you have the list of the before/after replacements, just copy it all into excel, run a VBA script and copy it out. I can help with that too. It might be the easier option.

Comment: Thanks. I'm familiar with excel vba but haven't touched it for a while. A script will be helpful !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK here's my solution. Copy all of your stuff from Notepad++ to a new excel workbook. It has to be in Sheet1. Copy all of your listed "Find" items in Column A of Sheet2. Put the matching "Replace" items in Column B of Sheet2. No headers on Sheet2 as it will search and replace the header values as well (unless you modify range "r" in the follow code to start at A2).

Run the following script:

```
Sub FindReplaceAll()
Dim FindString, ReplaceString As String
Dim r As Range

Set r = Sheet2.Range("A1")

Do While Not r.Value = 0
    FindString = r.Value
    ReplaceString = r.Offset(0, 1).Value

    Sheet1.Cells.Replace What:=FindString, Replacement:=ReplaceString, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)
Loop

MsgBox "Done!"

End Sub
```

This should search and replace all your entries one by one. Once it's done, you can copy it back to Notepad++. It'll stop at the first empty row so make sure you find/replace rows are continuous.

Just in case you're rusty with Excel Macros/Scripts, in excel, hit alt + F11, right click on the VBAProject in the tree on the left and select Insert > Module. Paste the code in the new box that appears and hit the play button (F5).

Hope this helps, best of luck!

Comment: Just so you know, it might appear as though excel has crashed, give it a few (read: I don't know. It's hard to say, it could take anywhere from a minute to 30?) minutes before you kill the process. 10,000 items and it has to do a replace all each time.

Comment: It worked but takes a long time !!

Comment: You should add `Application.Calculation=xlManual` and `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` to the start of your code and `Application.Calculation=xlAutomatic` and `Application.ScreenUpdating=True` to the end of your code. This will markedly improve the calculation time. Just remember that calculation and interaction with the worksheet are the biggest bottlenecks in Excel VBA.

Comment: I noticed something: It doesn't replace replace all possible matches. I have to paste chunk by chunk before it fully replaces everything. Maybe its the way Excel does comparison with arrays. Is there a workaround ?

Comment: What do you mean by paste chunk by chunk? Are you making sure that there are no empty rows (or more specifically, no empty cells in column a)?

Comment: OK. When I paste the entire text, for some reason a few tags are left unreplaced. If I remove everything but that section which has the unreplaced items, run the macro, the tags are replaced.

Comment: Are the tags all in a continuous group at the end, or are they mixed all over?